# Programar el botón "exit" en Java

Tags: java

Necesito cambiar la acción que se ejecuta al apromir en la 'X' de cierre que esta en la esquina de la ventana

Estuve mirando el método que cierra la ventana por defecto pero no da opción de personalizar

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Solo da 4 opciones que son:

```
DO_NOTING // No hace nada
DISPOSE // Cierra la ventana pero el programa continúa
HIDE // Oculta la ventana
EXIT // Finaliza el programa
```

Hay alguna alternativa para hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola puedes usar algo asi

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                    int i=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Seguro que quiere salir?");
                    if(i==0)
                        System.exit(0);//cierra aplicacion
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes hacer un boton que al pulsar se salga por ejemplo seria asi.

```
 private void botonSalirProductoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        System.exit(WIDTH);
 }
```

Comment: El problema es que quiero programar el botón de exit, de nada me sirve poner un botón que ayude a salir si el usuario oprime en la "X" y me cierra el programa, aunque no se si ese botón de la esquina se pueda deshabilitar